# Need to install pip on computer without internet

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, offline, python-wheel

I'm trying to download ultimately numpy and scipy on a computer running python 2.7 and that cannot connect to the internet. I've have the whl files for both of those on my computer but need to install them with pip which I also don't have. I've tried downloading the whl files for both pip and setuptools along with get-pip.py, and running python `get-pip.py --no-index --findlinks=`. but am now getting the error that it can't find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools. It appeared to load the pip whl file fine but pip still isn't installed. Any suggestions for how to get setuptools to match the requirement, or a simpler way to do this all together?

Comment: You might have better luck getting help [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaeology) ;)

Comment: yes, i know, I also feel stuck in the dark ages but I'm dealing with what i was given haha.

Comment: Consider Anaconda https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/. This gives you an installer that includes NumPy as well as many more packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setuptools` dropped support for Python 2 at version [45.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v45-0-0). So you need to [download version 44](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/44.0.0/#files).

Comment: That worked, thank you! I ended up also needing the wheel whl file but once i got both of those i had pip and was able to use it to download scipy and numpy.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark to the left. Thank you for using Stack Overflow, please come again!